# In vb formdesigner how to update underlaying table from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, datagridview

I have a datagridview bounded to a sql-server db. When I have made some changes in a cell I can save the changes to the database with a button:

```
    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Try
        Dim dlgResult As New DialogResult
        dlgResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the changes you made ?", "Confirmation !", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If dlgResult = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Try
                Me.tblInvoicesTableAdapter.Update(Me.dsInvoices.tblInvoices)
                MessageBox.Show("Updated successfully !", "Information :", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Update canceld !", "Information :", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            'Code for undo changes to dgv

            'some testcode - doesn't work
            Me.dgvInvoice.RefreshEdit()
            Me.dgvInvoice.Refresh()
            End If
  Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

How can I reset my changes in the `Else` statement of my `button_Click` event?

Comment: Thanks Ohbewise, solution works fine !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with a `DataTable` as your `DataSource`, you can simply call [`DataTable.RejectChanges()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rejectchanges(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2). According to MSDN documentation, this method:

> Rolls back all changes that have been made to the table since it was loaded, or the last time [AcceptChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) was called.